# How to wrap this Javascript up as a function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I have written the following JavaScript, a personal challenge in this case to write a sine function without the use of any native methods...

```js
f=n=>n<2?1:n*f(n-1)
p=(x,y)=>y--?x*p(x,y):1
w=(c,a)=>c()&&a()&w(c,a)
n=100;z=0; x=Math.PI/4
w(()=>n>-1,()=>{z+=p(-1,n)/f(2*n+1)*p(x,2*n+1),n--})
```

So when I output the value of z, I get the sine of x (i.e. the sine of Pi/4 radians)

I'd like to wrap this last line into a fat arrow function (i.e. s=x=>...Whatever it is... ) and have it spit out the value of z but my last few attempts have been fraught with failure... That way I can enter any value of X and have the sine of X spat out...

I'd like to keep the f, p and w functions separate in this case... I intend to use them later for other things...

Anyone have any clue as to how to achieve this given what I've got?

Thanks...

Comment: I can't figure out what this code is doing? Could you use more meaningful variable names, and format it neatly?

Comment: `f` is factorial? `w` looks like it has infinite recursion.

Comment: @Barmar f is factorial, p is equivalent to an integer power function and w is a while loop. The last line is the computation of a sine function based on the Taylor series...

Comment: Why such cryptic code? Are you practicing for a CodeGolf tournament?

Comment: @Barmar, LOL, Something like that... I'm looking into non-conventional ways of programming for a series of articles for my programming blog. I thought a trigonometric function rewritten in this manner may generate a little interest amongst my readers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `z` a local variable in the `s` function, and then return it from the function.

```js
f=n=>n<2?1:n*f(n-1);
p=(x,y)=>y--?x*p(x,y):1;
w=(c,a)=>c()&&a()&w(c,a);
s = x => {
    let z = 0, n = 100;
    w(()=>n>-1,()=>{z+=p(-1,n)/f(2*n+1)*p(x,2*n+1),n--});
    return z;
};
console.log(s(Math.PI/4));
```